# Get highest AVCaptureSessionPreset Available

Tags: ios, swift, image, camera, image-quality

I am working on a camera app, and I would like to make the camera as clear as possible. As I am using the front camera, I am currently using this:

```
captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
```

However, in some cases, the pictures turn out quite blurry. For each separate device, I want to find the preset that produces the clearest images, but won't crash the app. Previously, when I have tried to give too high-quality of a preset, the app crashes. How can I find the perfect preset for each device? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get device's camera maximun resolution,
You can asign highest resolution with:

captureSession.SessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.PresetPhoto;